# Crash DispatchQueue async with swift

Tags: swift

Hello the following code generates this exception for me, this app connect to remote node.js api rest server and get value for setup application. These values ​​are used to build a custom menu based on the rest calls made to node.js  the values ​​are verified with return calls boolean type value the strange thing is that it generates an app crash on the threads

**Error:**

```
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -..
2019-03-19 15:52:03.255375+0100 myapp[441:34081] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication delegate]
PID: 441, TID: 34081, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.root.user-interactive-qos, QoS: 33
Backtrace:
4   myapp                               0x00000001005ca3ac $S5myapp8DatabaseC12GetServerURLSSyF + 112
5   myapp                               0x00000001005c66a4 $S5myapp4JSONC15GetSingleString6Router10ValueArray10completionySS_SDySSypGySSctF + 608
6   myapp                               0x0000000100617a08 $S5myapp9UserModelC16VerificaPermesso09TipologiaE010completionySS_ySSctFyycfU_ + 456
7   myapp                               0x0000000100566510 $SIeg_IeyB_TR + 52
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001017f7824 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001017f8dc8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010180a330 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 716
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010180abc8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018404d17c _pthread_wqthread + 472
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018404fcec start_wqthread + 4
```

**Code:**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //Controllo permesso accesso cantieri
            self.u = User()


            //Controllo permesso accesso Clienti
            self.u.VerificaPermesso(TipologiaPermesso: "clienti", completion: { result in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if(result == "false") {
                        viewControllerList.remove(at: 4)
                        self.viewControllers = viewControllerList
                    }
                }
            });

            //Controllo permesso accesso Articoli
            self.u.VerificaPermesso(TipologiaPermesso: "articoli", completion: { result in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if(result == "false") {
                        viewControllerList.remove(at: 2)
                        self.viewControllers = viewControllerList
                    }
                }
            });

            //Controllo permesso accesso Magazzino
            self.u.VerificaPermesso(TipologiaPermesso: "magazzino", completion: { result in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if(result == "false") {
                        viewControllerList.remove(at: 5)
                        self.viewControllers = viewControllerList
                    }
                }
            });

            self.u.VerificaPermesso(TipologiaPermesso: "cantieri", completion: { result in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if(result == "false") {
                        viewControllerList.remove(at: 1)
                        self.viewControllers = viewControllerList
                    }
                }
            });


        }
```

**GetServerUrl Code:**

```
func GetServerURL() -> String {

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Setup")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
        do {
            let result = try context.fetch(request)
            if result.count > 0
                {
                for result in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
                    if let server = result.value(forKey: "server")as? String
                        {
                        self.serverSet = server

                    }

                    if let port = result.value(forKey: "port") as? Int32
                        {
                        self.portSet = "\(port)"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("Errore caricamento Parametri DB \(error)")

        }
        var ret = "\(serverSet):\(portSet)"
        if(serverSet == "" || portSet == "") {
            ret = ""
        }
        return ret

    }
```

Comment: myapp8DatabaseC12GetServerURLSSyF. What's the code of what I think is `GetServerURL`?

Comment: @Larme, https://www.swiftdemangler.com: `myapp.Database.GetServerURL() -> Swift.String`

Comment: Also, it worth noting, that it's not a crash, just a breakpoint by `Main Thread Checker`

Comment: i don't have  breakpoint

Comment: It's not regular breakpoint, it's breakpoint put there by `Pause on issues` option of `Main Thread Checker` in `Scheme Settings` on `Diagnostics` tab.

Answer (score 1):

According to your crashlog inside of `myapp.Database.GetServerURL` you trying to access `UIApplication.shared.delegate` which is UIKit api and should be performed on main thread.
Possible solutions:

- Wrap this call in `DispatchQueue.main.sync { ... }`.
  This will fix your error, but code smell and design error will stay and could hit you again in future
- Move this code from `AppDelegate` to model dependent layer.
  Since it's database related call, consider moving it inside separate Database service that maybe singleton (DB is good example of possible usage of singletons)